# How do you insert a custom HTML tag in Fulma/Fable?

Tags: html, f#, bulma, fable-f#

I'm using Fable (2) + Fulma (1.1) + Elmish (2) for a web UI and I want to add a Select dropdown as documented in Bulma [here](https://bulma.io/documentation/form/select/). It makes use of the `<option>` HTML tag for the items but I can't find this anywhere in the Fulma library. In this case, how can I write an arbitrary tag into my view?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The specific thing you need is [in Fulma](https://github.com/Fulma/Fulma/blob/0e7119cae66cf0f517a7cbf21e543235554975e6/src/Fulma/Elements/Form/Select.fs), but not immediately obvious in the documentation. It's there, but you need to look at the [Fulma docs for Form elements](https://fulma.github.io/Fulma/#fulma/elements/form) and look at their Form demo. There you'll see the following:

[image: Select dropdown]

The source code that produces this in the demo is this section:

```
   Field.div [ ]
        [ Label.label [ ]
            [ str "Subject" ]
          Control.div [ ]
            [ Select.select [ ]
                [ select [ DefaultValue "2" ]
                    [ option [ Value "1" ] [ str "Value n°1" ]
                      option [ Value "2"] [ str "Value n°2" ]
                      option [ Value "3"] [ str "Value n°3" ] ] ] ] ]
```

I don't yet know how to insert an arbitrary tag; once I find out, I'll edit this answer to include that detail. But this should solve your immediate problem.

**Edit:** As for how to create custom elements, here's what I found in the [Fable.React source](https://github.com/fable-compiler/fable-react/blob/10bb84d44db8fa0fa166c5f2fe3da5ba89af5485/src/Fable.React.Standard.fs):

```
open Fable.React

let inline a props children = domEl "a" props children
let inline abbr props children = domEl "abbr" props children
let inline address props children = domEl "address" props children
// ...
let inline hr props = voidEl "hr" props
let inline img props = voidEl "img" props
let inline input props = voidEl "input" props
// ...
let inline svg props children = svgEl "svg" props children
let inline circle props children = svgEl "circle" props children
let inline clipPath props children = svgEl "clipPath" props children
```

So there are three base functions in the `Fable.React` namespace: `domEl`, which takes a tag name, a list of properties, and a list of children; `voidEl`, which just takes a tag name and a list of properties (for tags that HTML defines as not having children), and `svgEl`, which is for elements that are part of an `<svg>` definition rather than HTML (though in practice it works exactly like `domEl`: [as you can see, their definitions are exactly identical in Fable.React](https://github.com/fable-compiler/fable-react/blob/ea0962c2d693998cc4816a78cff8d384bca52e49/src/Fable.React.Helpers.fs#L340)). To create a custom tag, you could either do:

```
domEl "customTag" [ ] [ children ]
```

Or:

```
let inline custom props children = domEl "customTag" props children
custom [ ] [ children ]
```

Comment: Ah hah! Thanks very much. Do let me know if you find out about the arbitrary tag, that would be very useful if I can't find my way around again in future. Also after all my Googling I somehow never managed to find that docs site so thanks for pointing it out, it looks like a big help.

Comment: Although, the `option` function doesn't seem to be in that GitHub page you linked, only the `Option` type for customising `Select`.

Comment: @user2163043 - Haven't found where the `option` function is defined, but I found the `Fable.React` source that illustrates how to create your own: see my answer edit.

Comment: @user2163043 - If you hadn't found the Fulma docs, you may not have seen the [Fulma demo](https://mangelmaxime.github.io/fulma-demo/) either: it's a good demo of what you can do, and its source will teach you a lot about how to organize a Fable codebase at a higher level.